# How do I connect an Azure MySQL Database to my iOS and Android App

Tags: android, ios, mysql, database, azure

Entirely new to this and was hoping to find some reasonably straightforward API's or documentation to connect the MySQL database I have on Azure to the iOS and Android apps I have in development.

What is needed to make this happen?

The database and structure are created - what does it take to accomplish something like this:

1. iOS / Android app connect to the DB in Azure
2. to file a report which will push 2 - 3 values to the server: x, y, z
3. update/increment the db with these values
4. allow for the DB to perform a push/pull of aggregated reports BACK to the iOS / Android apps

If all goes well - return to point 1.

I'm hoping there is a reasonably well-written document that will explain this step-by-step and I can work on this a little more this week.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a mobile backend for your apps to communicate with. This can be written in most languages but I'm from a .Net/c# background so all of mine have been in dotnet core. The API is what communicates with the database and in turn the API should be protected by an Identity Provider such as Azure Active Directory (or implement your own/use Google/Facebook etc).

This article is slightly outdated, but the concept remains the same... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mobile/native-mobile-backend?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Thanks very much - I believe you're spot on!  I was able to dig up these areas of documentation with some help!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-php

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-database-mysql

First link is under a section which has samples for Java, C++, Go, PHP, etc.